# XHR Ajax Requests

Tags: javascript, ajax, rest

Not sure what i'm doing wrong?

So using either Jquery/Axios/Qwest to send out a GET request with a token in the params like this gives me a error response of Invalid Token.

```js
    return qwest.get(this.portalURL + '/sharing/rest/content/groups/' + groupId, {
      token: token,
      f: 'json'
    });
```

However If I just browse to the URL The token works.  If I use POstman to do the request it works as well.

The Token Looks something like this

v_KUlcVsLJjO208JhCECbuYYlgS4NWB-b21eztZikgR2a9ZlBlCiIIdEMv8y4b510c1YwUp9IA_pbltvqT8-UeXebxO3nVBSSo4VxAZMD01P4OdpJXlqjcjHRVEOeCgv

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios) you can send Get params via

```
return qwest.get(this.portalURL + '/sharing/test/content/groups' + groupId, {
    params: {
        token: token,
        f: 'json'
    }
});
```